# Using a dynamic stylesheet with CodeIgniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, stylesheet

I have a dynamic PHP stylesheet, but I can't find a way to send variables to it so I used sessions instead. Figured this kinda sucked, so I'm going to give it another try but could need some help. It's an external stylesheet where a variable has effect through the whole document.

Comment: What about use a request in CI to get the file contents?

Comment: Just call the CSS file as a CI request, like `domain.tld/css/get/filename/params`

Comment: Would having multiple stylesheets be a legitimate solution? If so, you could use the controller to set the stylesheet file, and then load the file in the head of your document view accordingly.

Comment: Using the URL helper wound't help? 
$segments = array('news', 'local', '123');
echo site_url($segments);
Taken from http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an embedded stylesheet (a `<style>` block) in the page: it increases the size of the main page, but solves the variable access issue without needing sessions and reduces your number of requests. You can just load your dynamic stylesheet into the main page's view using `load->view`.

EDIT: Ah, massive amounts of CSS would be one problem. Well, two alternatives are to:

1. Turn on the `$_GET` support in your CI install, you COULD pass in a request parameter in the CSS link and then check for the request parameter in the PHP controller or view file that generates the actual CSS. Not visually the tidiest option, but it does work.
2. Put in a cookie that you check in the controller that gets called for the CSS: you can then check that in the controller or view and do the right thing. Visually much tidier than the request parameter option, but a bit more involved.

Comment: I already thought of this, but I rather not have thousands of lines of CSS in the main page. Setting the variable in a <style> block could work, but then it wouldn't be sent through the external stylesheet.